# How to uninstall macports without doing a migration?

Tags: macos, macports

I'm currently using MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5. I would like to uninstall MacPorts on my macbook.

Based on the instructions here:

https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html

I should do the following

```
$ sudo port -fp uninstall installed
```

Here is the response I see:

```
Error: Current platform "darwin 17" does not match expected platform "darwin 16"
Error: If you upgraded your OS, please follow the migration instructions: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration
OS platform mismatch
    while executing
"mportinit ui_options global_options global_variations"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: Failed to initialize MacPorts, OS platform mismatch
```

Do I really need to do a migration first before uninstalling? Is there a way to install directly now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vast majority of MacPorts-installed stuff goes into /opt/local. You can, of course, delete that using:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/local
```

I know of a couple of ports which install stuff into /Applications/MacPorts, so you could also do this to catch that stuff:

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/MacPorts
```

I have one port which has installed a launch daemon in /Library/LaunchDaemons, so:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.*
```

You could check similar places like /Library/LaunchAgents and the corresponding directories in ~/Library.

---

Actually, the link you provided in your question tells you what to do:

> ```
> $ sudo rm -rf \
>         /opt/local \
>         /Applications/DarwinPorts \
>         /Applications/MacPorts \
>         /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* \
>         /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg \
>         /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \
>         /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \
>         /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \
>         /Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \
>         ~/.macports
> ```

Comment: But the link doesn't specifically say "this command is what you use if the port command doesn't work." I suppose it's obvious if  you're a Macports expert, but the doc isn't written for experts, is it?

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch To me, the instructions read something like "conditional first step, unconditional second step". That is, you always do the above `sudo rm -rf ...` command regardless of whether or not `port` is functioning. But, if `port` is functioning, do the `sudo port -fp uninstall installed` command before that.

Answer (score 2):

While the vast majority of files are installed in `/opt/local`, `/Applications/MacPorts` or `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.*`, there are a few ports that install files in other locations, e.g. due to operating system requirements. Depending on whether or not you had such ports installed, the solution by Ken (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50670316/2127896) may leave some files behind.

If you want to make sure that you caught all files, follow the [MacPorts migration instructions](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration) until step 3, i.e. basically reinstall MacPorts base (for example by running the installer). This should only take a couple of minutes.

Then, follow https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling, i.e. run

```
$ sudo port -fp uninstall installed
```

and then the `rm -rf` command already mentioned in Ken's answer.